# What is the 'extobj' parameter in numpy functions?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

Reading the numpy documentation, I noticed that every numpy math function (like `add`, `multiply`, `log` etc.) has an `extobj` optional argument. The [documentation of the ufunc kwargs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-kwargs) says the following:

> A list of length 3 specifying the ufunc buffer-size, the error mode integer, and the error call-back function. Normally, these values are looked up in a thread-specific dictionary. Passing them here circumvents that look up and uses the low-level specification provided for the error mode. This may be useful, for example, as an optimization for calculations requiring many ufunc calls on small arrays in a loop.

If I understand correctly, it is possible to preallocate a buffer, where the calculations would take place,  making it unnecessary to allocate memory for internal calculations. I was browsing the internet to learn how to use this argument, but found nothing, not even in the official numpy documentation.

What is the proper way to use `extobj`? In what scenarios would this be useful?

Comment: My guess is that this is an advanced feature, that few SO level users have ever needed.  Does this SO have anything to do with your previous one about partial iterations?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, it came up related to the same project, but also I would like to learn a bit more about numpy and its optimization in general. But I can see that if no one previously asked about it, it might be something very special.

Comment: It seems like this layer is not really documented, you may need to check the source code to see how it works.